# How can I tackle this OOP design problem?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have a system that has 3 components:

**Report** - Contains logic for defining what a report actually contains in its output. Examples include `TopMerchantsReport` and `LowestTransactionsReport`.

**ReportRunner** - As the reports only do data gathering and generating, this class is responsible for running all of the reports and dispatching the results (via email, for example). Each `Report` has its own `ReportRunner`.

**ReportProfile** - Object mirror of a database table that contains a user's settings for a specific report.

---

A `Report` can have multiple pluggable behaviors, such as being `Digestable` and/or being `Schedulable`. Since PHP has no mixins, this is best represented by the decorator pattern.

My actual problem is that each of these 3 objects needs its behavior modified when the associated `Report` is decorated with something like `Schedulable`. For example, the `ReportRunner` now needs to only gather scheduled reports, and `ReportProfile` would benefit from a `isScheduled()` method.

I don't want to force a user to have to decorate all 3 classes. Not only is that error prone, but then I'd have to create 3 decorators for each behavior (one for each class). What other solution is there?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Report{
    const SCHEDULED = 1;  
    const DIGESTABLE = 2;  

    private $behaviour;  

    public function getReportData(){}  
    public function getReportProfile(){}  
    public function getBehaviour(){
        return $this->behaviour;
    }
}  

class ReportRunner{  
    public function runReport(){  
        switch($this->report->getBehaviour()){  
            case Report::SCHEDULED
            //do sheduled stuff  
            case Report::DIGESTABLE
            //do DIGESTABLE stuff  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have for a concrete class of e.g. Report different behaviour in other two components, you have to eventually decorate them, so you cannot avoid that. The only problem migth be managing creation of those three components to be decorated according to choosen behaviour e.g. Digestable. This can be done using a factory method pattern, which allows you to create appropriate kind of all those three components.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of, if I understand your ordeal properly, is to use the Factory Design. It will be the Factory's responsibility to supply the ReportRunner and ReportProfile that corresponds to a particular Report based on its decoration.

So you'd have a class for each ReportRunner and one for ReportProfile, quite similar.

**ReportRunner Factory** should have a method that takes in the Report's decoration and returns it's ReportRunner so you'd do something like:

```
report->setReportRunner(  factoryReportRunner->getReportRunner(report->getDecorationType()  );
```

In the FactoryReportRunner class you'd have a method of **getReportRunner(...)**

```
getReportRunner(decorationType){
     $functionToCall = $this->'get'.decorationType.'ReportRunner';
     if(function_exists($functionToCall) && 
                      is_callable(array($this, $functionToCall))){
         return $this->$functionToCall();
     }else{
         //log or alert as error
     }
}
```

Of course, then you'd have to have a **getDecorationReportRunner** for each decoration type, in this case: **getDigestableReportRunner** and **getSchedulableReportRunner**. The same would go for the factory for ReportProfile. This way, any time you add a new decoration type, all you have to is add the corresponding **getDecorationReportRunner** and the one that goes with ReportProfile too.